# Associating a timer on flag click on individual nodes for individual users

Tags: 7, nodes, users, datetime

I have a custom field "Time to Finish" in my custom content type in Drupal7. The "Time to Finish" is basically a timer of sorts. whenever the users click a flag (which is placed on nodes of that custom content type) the timer should start. The difficulty associated with this is that:

> 1. Every node of that content type has different Time to Finish
> 2. The timer should start on flag click (the flag is same on all node, "Start Flag")
> 3. Every user would have their own timer then depending on when they click on the Start Flag

The admin while creating the content **should** have the option to fill in the field "Time to Finish" and on flag click the timer should start. Any suggestions. Would really appreciate it.

Thanks

**Edit: I found this module which solves half of my issue,i.e, to assign every individual node their own Time To Finish field. [Countdown Timer Field](http://drupal.org/project/field_countdown) helped with this. Now i need that on "START FLAG" click the timer should start, not before that.**

EDIT 2: i have opened a feature request issue for this at http://drupal.org/node/1948958 but can anyone help me do this. It will not only solve my use case but i think is a necessary feature to be added

EDIT 3: if there is any other solution i am eager to hear it as well.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the time is up?

Comment: well nothing much...just a plain simple message displayed, say, "Sorry Time's UP" ...Also there is another flag, "Stop" which on click stops the timer

Comment: What sort of time period would this be? seconds? hours? days? How accurate does the timer need to be?

Comment: DHM would be fine

Comment: Sorry, you missed the point of my question so maybe I didn't put it clearly enough. How long would a typical timer be? I guess from your answer it would be several days? And I assume there's some operation that will be blocked after this time, so the message will be in response to someone trying it. Is that correct?

Comment: yes...you are right...i have edited the question now...let me try to be more clear..(sorry for any confusion if i caused). There is a field, Time to Finish, of type countdown timer (thanks to Countdown Timer Field module) in my content type. The admin while creating the content fill in a time there. Now when the users of my site go to that node the timer is already running. I do not want this. On this node there are two flags. "START" and "STOP". SO when the user clicks on "START" then ONLY the timer should start. AND on clicking on "STOP" the timer would stop and disappear.I hope m clear now

Comment: i was hoping that it could be done by the Rules module maybe but am unable to configure any action for it

Comment: a typical timer may be of a few days

Comment: Rules was what I was going to suggest but I was trying to understand the precise nature of your requirement. You'll need triggers when the flag is set / unset. If you are using the Flag module it comes with Rules integration.

Comment: yes i am using the Flag and Rules and i know how to set actions and triggers but i am unable to find any action which for my use case, i.e, to start the timer which is a field in my content type

Comment: i have opened a feature request issue for this at http://drupal.org/node/1948958 but can anyone help me do this. It will not only solve my use case but i think is a necessary feature to be added

Comment: maybe we can apply a patch as well....i am also all ears for any other solution as well, but in my view this approach would be the most elegant one

Comment: u need to do custom code. create a tpl file for field `field--field-name.tpl.php`

Comment: @monymirza ...yes i understand that but am not sure what to do and also if the field timer gets started for one user while he visits the node and clicks on START, it is essential that for other user it does not start unless the other user himself clicks the START flag...herein lies the complexity...i would really appreciate some help..m new to Drupal but m also ready and willing to write code for it but i need help

Comment: timer instantly starts when page load. So, u need to load function on click.

Comment: thats the problem ain't it...its not just a timer..its a field

Comment: so any help or suggestions regarding this

Comment: try my answer, hope it will work

Comment: so i guess it cant be done ???

Answer (score 1):

Create tpl file for field `field--field-name.tpl.php`. place it to your

> if Field nameis: **field_page_photos** 
> then File name will: **field--field-page-photos.tpl.php**

clear cache.

paste below code to your tpl field file.

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="start-timer">START FLAG</div>
  <div class="starttime">
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
(function($){$('.starttime').hide();$('.start-timer').click(function(){$('.starttime').show();});})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: well it does solve one part of the problem....the timer starts on click but if i log in as another user then on click the timer appears but it has already count down the time since the earlier click by other logged in user

Comment: what i want is that each user would see a different timer( i understand its not an easy task but well...)..its something quite practical

Comment: different timer not possible. u need something other then Countdown Timer Field.

Comment: and what may that be...any suggestions

Comment: Sounds like you are attaching the field to the node & not the user. You would probably want a reference to the node it's n also, and in the field let it have unlimited number, that way the user could have 2 of the same timers going and you could check if they have >3 and say they have to many. Anyhow attaching it to the user will fix it per user for 1 timer per user.